# How to change Type from varchar to Date without losing Data in Xamp

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I have my sql database which have a field date and its type is varchar,I want to convert it into the Date but i have a lot of record in this field.
Kindly guide me how i can covert it into Date type without loosing my data.
It's looking like : 20-10-2018
But i want to change the date column varchar type to Date.
Thanks.

Comment: How does the data look in your table ?

Comment: It;s looking like:
20-10-2018

Comment: But i want to change the type of the date column from varchar to Date

Comment: Please edit the question to add this details

Comment: I have added this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first need to convert the date string (varchar) to [MySQL date format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) (**YYYY-MM-DD**). We can use [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function for this.

Your sample date string (*20-10-2018*) is basically in **dd-mm-yyyy** format. Following format specifiers can be used:

- `%d`     Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31)
- `%m`     Month name as a numeric value (00 to 12)
- `%Y`     Year as a numeric, 4-digit value

The query to update the date would look as follows (**[DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/yWA44a8S8tsmBgXg7qfS2/0)**):

```
UPDATE your_table_name 
SET date_column_name = STR_TO_DATE(date_column_name, '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Now, you can use [`Alter Table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) to change the data type from `varchar` to `date`.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name 
MODIFY COLUMN date_column_name date;
```

Comment: it works but it changes the date record into this formate like YYYY-MM-DD but i needed it into DD-MM-YYYY formate because this record is being used at many places in my project so that's why then i have to change it within the whole project??

Comment: @AmmarMehr Please read about MySQL date format. It is YYYY-MM-DD only.